# Get current user id from token nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm very new to nodejs and mongodb, I have worked on app where users must login to get his joined courses list, so what I want to do when frontend ask for the course list to let backend(nodejs & mongodb) to validate the course list by compare the user id by the user id stored in the courses list (get current user id from token)
so the get from frontend is:

```
    http://localhost:3000/api/v1/courses/courses-list
router.get(`/courses/courses-list, async (req, res) =>{

  const coursesList = await 
 Course.find({user:ObjectId(//Here how to get current login user id from token)});
```

I'm using JWT for login and it works fine and store the token in the header but I don't know how to retrieve the token from nodejs

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jwt.verify()`

For example in my case

```
jwt.verify(token, mySecretKey, (err, result) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  // Result is the data I use when signing the token. 
  // id, username, etc.
});
```

Comment: this solution is not work for me, I hope you understood my question, all I need to get the current logged user information in nodejs